# I have a problem after converting the kivymd code where the application closes

Tags: android

I have a kivymd code. I converted to an Android program on google colab by following these commands, and with this program it opens and then closes. Can someone help me solve the problem?

Commands:
➡!pip install buildozer

➡!sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-17-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev

➡!pip install cython==0.29.33

➡!sudo apt-get install -y 
python3-pip 
build-essential 
git 
python3 
python3-dev 
ffmpeg 
libsdl2-dev 
libsdl2-image-dev 
libsdl2-mixer-dev 
libsdl2-ttf-dev 
libportmidi-dev 
libswscale-dev 
libavformat-dev 
libavcodec-dev 
zlib1g-dev

➡!sudo apt-get install -y 
libgstreamer1.0 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good

➡!sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi7

➡!sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

Now before running the next command upload your Python file

➡ !buildozer init

Next, scroll down to the requirements and change them as follows:
requirements = python3, kivy, kivymd, pillow

➡!buildozer -v android debug

I expected the program to work properly, but it opens the waiting image and then closes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You've mentioned how you built the program; but you haven't explained how you tried debugging your program.  You state that it opens the waiting image and then closes.  Then find out where that is in your code and debug from there.  As you haven't included any pertinent info on this debugging issue, there's little anyone can do to help.

Comment: I am a beginner and I do not know how to debug if the code becomes an apk program